# AngularJS scope inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var coutas = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    coutas.push(JSON.parse(d[i].coutas));
  }

 for (var i = 0; i < coutas.length; i++) {
    $scope.coutas = coutas[i];
 }
```

**That doesn't work**

what I try to do is assign the variable coutas the scope.coutas

i'm using two for loop because that :

[image]

the firt loop , It is to tour the first array,
and the second loop is to tour the seconds array

example : the firts loop tour the array 0 but inside the array 9 they are 22 objets.

i want that : 
[image]

Comment: Why are you using the second `for` loop? Why do you not do so `$scope.coutas = coutas`?

Comment: Also your $scope.coutas will only grab the last value in the array. if you are planning to store the entire array then just assign `$scope.coutas = coutas` like @DmitriyLoskutov suggested.

Comment: you can use `$scope.coutas.push()` so no need to use second for loop

Comment: Also you could have just used `$scope.coutas = coutas`

Comment: You should describe your question clearly. what your data and what do you want? also can you create plunker demo using demo data ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two for loop you may solve this problem using single loop. In your solution you generate `coutas` array in first loop then in second loop assigned only last info of `var coutas` in angular variable not whole  `coutas`.

One process can be assign whole `coutas` after first loop.

like:

`$scope.coutas = coutas`

or you can push in `$scope.coutas` in first loop.

like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    $scope.coutas.push(d[i].coutas); // if need to parse then use JSON.parse(d[i].coutas)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to require two loop ,if u did then define $scope.coutas =[ ] and push the arrar of every looping item;

```
   var coutas = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    coutas.push(JSON.parse(d[i].coutas));
  }
$scope.coutas =[];
 for (var i = 0; i < coutas.length; i++) {
    $scope.coutas.push(coutas[i]);
 }
```